# If A and B are $m by n$ matrices such that B$w$=A$w$ for all $w$ in $R^n$, then B=A.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I adopt clear logical formulas and hope it will make communication at ease.

I was just curious how vectors other than standard vectors make the statement (B$w$=A$w$) true?

> Given: $\forall w \in R^n$(B$w$=A$w$)

> Goal: B=A.

How do I prove this in 3 different approaches appropriately?

**1.Direct Proof**

The given is

> $\forall w \in R^n$(B$w$=A$w$)

We may select

$e_j \in R^n$ = the $j$th standar vectors in $R^n$

> $\forall e_j \in R^n$(B$e_j$=A$e_j$)

Each coulumn of B is equal to each column of A.

> B$e_j$ = the $j$th column of B,
> A$e_j$ = the $j$th column of A

This results in the goal

> B=A

**2.Proof by Contrapositive**

> Given: B $\neq$ A.

> Goal: $\exists w \in R^n$(B$w$$\neq$A$w$)

The given is

> B $\neq$ A.

It is obvious that some ($i,j$)-entry of B is not equal to the ($i,j$)-entry of A

> $\exists i \exists j $$b_i$$_j$ $\neq$ $a_i$$_j$

The $j$th column of B is not equal to the $j$th column of A.

> $\pmb b_j$ = The $j$th column of B,
> $\pmb a_j$ = The $j$th column of A,
> $\exists j$  B$e_j$ =$\pmb b_j$ $\neq$ $\pmb a_j$ = A$e_j$,
> $\exists e_j \in R^n$(B$e_j$ $\neq$ A$e_j$)

The goal is reached.

> Goal: $\exists w \in R^n$(B$w$$\neq$A$w$)

**3.Proof by Contradiction**

It is quite similar to proof by contrapositive.

> Given:$\forall w \in R^n$(B$w$=A$w$)
> Given:B$\neq$A

> Goal:Contradiction

The first given is equivalent to

> $\neg \exists w \in R^n$(B$w$ $\neq$ A$w$)

The second given is equivalent to

> $\exists e_j \in R^n$(B$e_j$ $\neq$ A$e_j$)

We reach a contradiction which meets our goal.

> Goal: $\neg \exists w \in R^n$(B$w$ $\neq$ A$w$) $\land$ $\exists e_j \in R^n$(B$e_j$ $\neq$ A$e_j$)

Comment: Hint for 1): if the equality holds for vectors $w_1,\dots,w_n$, then with $W=[w_1,\dots,w_n]$, $AW=BW$. For 2): if $B\ne A$, then $B-A$ is nonzero.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Sustitude standard vectors of R^n e_1,e_2,...e_n for w_1,...w_n?

Comment: That would be a good idea.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I am not sure if it is good enough to become a correct proof. why or why not?

Comment: when w is not standard vectors, how to make the proof exhaustive.

Comment: $w$ is any vector, why not pick the vectors that will answer the question directly? Once you write $AI=BI$, you have immediately $A=B$.

Comment: I just felt that it is needed to prove vectors which are not standard vectors.

Comment: Nope. And it's an important point you really have to understand, as it's true in general and it's often how proofs work: If you have to prove $(\forall x, P(x)) \implies Q$, then it may happen that a wise choice of $x$ proves $Q$. It's your duty to put the hypotheses to good use. And the simplest choice (that works), the better.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut You classify the logical form of this proof as (∀x,P(x))⟹Q. But why not ∀x(P(x)⟹Q). Both are similar to me. Are both correct for this proof?

Comment: They are absolutely not equivalent. The first (which is your statement), means that if $P(x)$ is true for all $x$, then $Q$ is true. If it help you may choose any $x$ you wish to prove $Q$. The other means: for all $x$, (if $P(x)$ is true then $Q$ is true). Now, you habe to prove the implication works for any choice of $x$. But here it wouldn't work: you can't prove that as it's wrong, and you need several different (and linearly independent) vectors $w$ to prove $A=B$.

Comment: Right, I was stuck by that similarity. I started with ∀x(P(x)⟹Q) and tried to proof by converse and by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

direct proof: Let $\mathbf w_s$ be the column vector of length $n$ with 1 in position $s$ and 0's elsewhere. Let $M$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Then the element in position $r$ of $M\mathbf w_s$ is $m_{rs}$.Thus the element in position $r$ of $A\mathbf w_s$ is $a_{rs}$ and the element in position $r$ of $B\mathbf w_s$ is $b_{rs}$. Since $a_{rs}=b_{rs} \text{ for all }r,s$, the matrices $A$ and $B$ are identical.

Comment: I see. Even only finite vectors are chosen. Which are standard vectors. But this results to a useful step that each column of B is equal to each corresponding column of A.

Comment: But I still wonder about those vectors which are not standard vectors but also make the proof correct. How and why?